# Add value of columns in foreach loop.

Tags: php, mysql

I have quantity in two diff tables . i want to add those quantities and update it into table3 amount column.
I have wrote this code but the value is showing 0
foreach($products as $key =>$value)
    {

```
 echo $totalquantity = $value->amount+ $value->QuantityAvailable;
 $updtqry="UPDATE stock SET amount = $totalquantity where id_stock='".$value->id_stock."'";
 mysql_query($updtqry); 

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the code you've put in your question? I don't see how it's connected to the question.

Comment: I just want to know how to get a sum of array values within foreach loop

Comment: So do you intend to get the sum of all the elements in one particular array...??

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know how to get a sum of array values within foreach loop

Well you get sum of two arrays containing numeric values like this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($amountArray as $amount) {
     $sum += $amount;
}

foreach($amountArray2 as $amount) {
     $sum += amount;
}

// update with $sum...
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) If you want to find the sum of the elements of one particular array. You could use array_sum().

```
array_sum($array1);
```

2.) If you want to get the sum of two array you could do it the following way, provided the arrays are numerically indexed.

```
for($index=0; $index < count($array1); $index++) {
   $array3[$index] = $array1[$index] + $array2[$index];
}
```

Here `$array1` and `$array2` are the values of which are to be added and stored in `$array3`.

3.) If the arrays are not numerically indexed then you could do this:

```
for ($counter=0;$counter<count($array1);$counter++) {
    $array3[$counter] = current($array1) + current($array2);
    next($array1); next($array2);
}
```

The number of the elements of the two arrays should be equal for it to work.